# Discord.js v12 How to get the id of a person who reacted on a specific message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

Im making my own ticket bot right now! So first of all the bot sent a embed where you can react if you want to create a ticket (When you react the bot will create a new channel in a specific category).I changed the permissions of this category so that @everyone cant see that channel.

My question is how to change the permission so that the user who reacted can write and see his ticket-channel.

My code is:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reactionReaction, user) => {

    const message = reactionReaction.message;
    const verifyChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('724929149755719751');
    const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
    const guild = message.guild;
    if (member.user.bot) return;
    if (reactionReaction.emoji.name === '' && message.channel.id === verifyChannel.id) {
        guild.channels.create('Factions', { type: 'text', parent: '724929049612386375' });
        await reactionReaction.users.remove(member).catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `options.permissionOverwrites[]` from the [`GuildChannel.create(name, options)` method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create)

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reactionReaction, user) => {
  const message = reactionReaction.message;
  const verifyChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("724929149755719751");
  const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
  const guild = message.guild;
  if (member.user.bot) return;
  if (
    reactionReaction.emoji.name === "" &&
    message.channel.id === verifyChannel.id
  ) {
    guild.channels.create("Factions", {
      type: "text",
      parent: "724929049612386375",
      permissionOverwrites: [
        {
          id: user.id,
          allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"],
        },
      ],
    });
    await reactionReaction.users.remove(member).catch(console.error);
  }
});
```